# Rollback MySQL transaction if user hits refresh during a php POST request

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, transactions

is there a way I can rollback a MySQL query if the user **clicks on F5** or **stops and resubmits** the request during a **lengthy process**?

I tried using http://php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php like this:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
$val = $this->setPINToUsed($request->registrationpin);
sleep(15);
if (connection_aborted() == 1) {
  DB::rollBack();
}else{
  DB::commit();  
}
```

How can I go about fixing this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably only need to add this directive: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php

Comment: I set `ignore_user_abort(false);` but after manually cancelling request, the request wasn't rolled back.
Thanks

Comment: You should set `ignore_user_abort(true)` if you want your php to run even after user aborts the request. Otherwise the script "ends" right after the user closes the page.

Answer (score 0):

While it is technically possible to do what you ask, you *really* shouldn't do it.

It's generally a bad idea to run a transaction, that shouldn't always be applied. Also, it's bad to put a lengthy process in the hands of a client.  There is a great amount of edge cases, like the fact that, you cannot be sure that php will know that the user aborted and you'll have logic, that will break from time to time.

It's much better to run the transaction in a queue, and ask the user to wait a few seconds (.. or minutes?). You could provide occasional updates through an AJAX request.

Comment: How can I **run the transaction in a queue** without putting it in the function?

Comment: I don't think I really understand your question.

Comment: "It's much better to run the transaction in a queue". How do I do this?

Comment: Assuming you're running Laravel, you should create a new job and dispatch it. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues